# Uploading file in behat using relative path

Tags: php, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, behat

Is it possible to upload file during test using behat and Selenium2 with relative path? I am doing it like this in my Page Class:

```
 $element = $this->getElement('Upload file');
 $element->attachFile('full_path_to_file');
```

When I am using full path it works just fine, but it doesn't work with relative path. Can I somehow configure it in behat.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your current working directory is

```
C:\Programs\php\directory
```

and the file you want to upload is in:

```
C:\Programs\php\directory\images\image.png
```

---

Then you can use `getcwd()` like this:

```
$element = $this->getElement('Upload file');
$element -> attachFile(getcwd() . '\images\image.png');
```